# Symmetric complex matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, definition, symmetric-matrices

Is this matrix symmetric?

$$ A=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 0 & (1+i) \\
    0 & 3 & -1 \\
    (1-i) & -1 & 3 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

The $a_{13}$ and $a_{31}$ entries are not visually the same. I would probably look at the magnitude of these given complex number which is for both equal to the same number. Is it okay?

I know this question is trivial but I am somehow confused.

Comment: This is self-adjoint.  In symmetric matrices, $a_{ij} = a{ji}$.  To make this question complete, please quote relevant definitions.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會  The only mathematical term the OP used is "symmetric", and I don't think that needs to be defined. Also, you need an underscore before your $ji$.

Comment: @bubba I suppose that including [relevant definitions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29355/290189) is a way to provide context for the question

Answer (score 0):

Since $a_{31}\neq a_{13}$, it is not symmetric. But it is a [Hermitian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix).